# how to handle the UI of a dialog ,when i call that same dialog method in the click of some buttons

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout, android-fragments

i have alert dialog with list of items and on click to every item  i have to show an another alert dialog ie same for all,
but the issue is that in 2nd dialog I need wo set some Text field in visible , how can it do that??
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2QBJJ.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fpj5D.png)

Comment: Please don't post images of code. You should [edit] your question and post code snippets that are important for your question here.

Comment: What text do you want to set or be visible in the 2nd dialog exactly?

Answer (score 0):

If it's the "vital option" string you want to show in the next dialog, then when calling the showDateDialog method you can pass the "s" variable to that method and use it as text in a `TextField`.

```java
String s = vitalOption[i];
showDateDialog(s);

void showDateDialog(s: String) {
   yourTextField.text = s;
}
```